# What is the origin of sense data?

Tags: empiricism, sense-data

Did Ayer and other sense data theorists believe that sense data are caused by the external world somehow? I don't know if this is supposed to be controversial, but I just don't see how you can deny this without denying neuroscientific accounts of perception. Also, how can sense data be about the external world if it isn't caused by the external world?

Comment: As far as I know solipsism and some variants of advaita are the only positions which negate the existence of an external word. But of course, also the adherents of these positions act according to the stimuli of their sense organs. - It is a remarkable fact that one cannot rebut a solipsist by argumentation.

Comment: Yes, they are produced by the interaction of external phenomena: light, sound, i.e. waves of some sort, with our sense organs.

Comment: One might consider sense data to be caused by an external world, but sense data theory is also compatible with idealism, so it would be possible to consider the world to be a construction from sense data, rather than the cause of it.

Comment: "sense data" are ever (somewhat) "wrong" ..but there is a "common sense" and math, "statistics", "confidence",  physics ..a.s.f. ..it is getting also interesting, when sense data is not caused by external data, but (e.g.) by (mass!?) "hallucination"/dream

Comment: ...if sense data was totally "unrelated to external world", then i guess there would be much less "life forms" "in our periphery" (if at all)

Comment: Zen master, "Does this rock exist inside or outside your mind?" Zen student, "Inside my mind." Zen master, "Your head must feel very heavy if you are carrying around a rock like that inside your mind!" Qualia are perceptions of the rock independent of concepts used to describe and discuss the rock using language. Rocks have attributes in common based on concepts of perceptions so we call them rocks. What do the perceptions, concepts, and discussions of rocks have to do with reality apart from human generated ideas of reality? Absolutely nothing! Reducing perceptions to concepts of atoms etc.

Answer (score 5):

A good start is here at the [SEP's Sense Data](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sense-data/#FurtDeveClasNotiSensData), and since I'm no expert, I'd encourage you to read it and prefer it where my answer differs.

In the classic conception, our representations are free of imagination (to use Humean language), and are essentially objective projections of the world into us, as far as [intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sense-data/#FurtDeveClasNotiSensData) is concerned. This drives the notion that our observations, which are essentially a composition of our sense data are objective.

But, by the time the logical positivists came around and pursued their programme of trying to reduce theoretical statements to observation statements, it started to become clear that objective observation dissolves on close inspection. At first, the argument is that our observations are biased by our theoretical frameworks, an idea known as [theory-ladenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness). From WP:

> Semantic theory-ladenness refers to the impact of theoretical assumptions on the meaning of observational terms while perceptual theory-ladenness refers to their impact on the perceptual experience itself.

The latter notion is taken up with vigor by [conceptualists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptualism) like John McDowell who argue that the spontaneity of sense data betrays the selective nature of how our conceptual framework biases our perceptions irrevocably. From the WP article:

> Thus, in rejecting the Myth of the Given, McDowell argues for perceptual conceptualism, according to which perceptual content is conceptual "from the ground up", that is, all perceptual experience is a form of conceptual experience. McDowell's philosophy of justification is considered a form of foundationalism: it is a form of foundationalism because it allows that certain judgements are warranted by experience and it is a coherent form of this view because it maintains that experience can warrant certain judgements because experience is irreducibly conceptual.

Famously, this term 'Myth of the Given' originates with Wilfrid Sellers who is perhaps best known for his [*Empiricism and the Philosophy of Mind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfrid_Sellars#%22Empiricism_and_the_Philosophy_of_Mind%22). Sellars, a neo-Kantian thinker, attacked the foundations of sense data by insisting that the spontaneous presentation of the foundation of our observations isn't object, but rather is interdependent with the concepts it depends on. From section 38 of the essay:

> The idea that observation "strictly and properly so-called" is constituted by certain self-authenticating nonverbal episodes, the authority of which is transmitted to verbal and quasi-verbal performances when these performances are made in "conformity with the semantical rules of the language," is, of course, the heart of the Myth of the Given.

He goes on to say that empirical knowledge and observation is not rational because it is foundational, but because, like Quine delineates as Neurath's boat, we can self correct. Of course, we are out in the sea, and can only replace one mistaken plank at a time. But no plank is ultimately foundational or irreplaceable. Thus, the appeal to the incorrigibility of observation and empirical access of sense data are at best, like the planks, useful until they no longer are.

Thus, the controversy is not that sense data conflict with neuroscience, but that neuroscience supports the thesis that sense data aren't direct representations of the world but are normative consistent with [predictive coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_coding) for instance. Thus, our perceptions or observations are quite literally constructions applied to raw sense information in the nervous system and are demonstrably subjective to some degree.

At least, that's my understanding. From the SEP article:

> [S]ense data fell out of favor in the 1960s and 1970s. But there have been attempts to restore some version of the theory. Often, but not always, these efforts sought to sustain mental sense data as the immediate objects of perception... The argument that sense data are all mental proceeds for the case of vision by seeking to establish that colors are mental items. The argument is indirect, from the conclusion that colors are not physical. This conclusion, in turn, relies on the claim that color is not a “scientific property”, that only scientific properties exist in the external world and affect the eyes and brain, and that color then can only be a mental entity caused by neural activity... The argument relies on a conception of scientific or physical properties that is widespread in philosophy: that physics has no place for phenomenal properties or perceptual experience.

Notably, [John Searle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Searle) still defends this sort of immediacy of apprehension free of conceptual processing in his theory of direct realism in his [*Seeing Things as They Are* (GB)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Seeing_Things_as_They_are/3jfvBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=how%20things%20are%20searle&printsec=frontcover). He attacks a representational theory of mind as a misguided effort by the entire Western philosophical canon.

Comment: +1 for a good answer!

Comment: @MarcoOcram Thanks. It's my understanding of the matter anyway. Always looking for holes in my understanding, so don't hesitate to heap lavish criticism on my response.

Comment: I think it would help to get Sellars' *Empiricism and the Philosophy of Mind* into the answer since that basically reframed the whole discourse away from any sense data, including vocabulary that is still used whenever people discuss the immediacy of sensual input (or lack thereof).

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Of course, good sir. Done. A quote from section 38, as best as this feeble non-philosopher, apprehends. As always, I thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

The issue about perception, and the difficulty in explaining it in physicalist terms, is outlined in SEP's article on [The Problem of Perception](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/perception-problem/).

The most common view of perception is that our nerves detect inputs from the external world, then our unconscious mind digests this data down, and presents a highly hypothesis/tuned interpretation of it to our awareness.  This presentation includes the qualia of our experience, and also includes embedded hypothesis about the meaning of those qualia.

This description is what our neuroscience has revealed.  Our sensors -- such as our eardrum resonances, are NOT what we perceive.  We have no awareness of the jitter of our eyes to create a field of view, or the nulling out of background noise that is part of our hearing sensing.  Our acoustic sensing, thermal sensing, and photodetectors acquire a much greater range of data than our conscious mind can process, and our unconscious sorts it into things that seem to matter -- such as the sound of footsteps is amplified vs our own heartbeat.  Face-type shapes are highlighted, vs the random color patterns that our eyes often pick up.  The pattern recognition and priority sorting by our unconscious minds have been a major area uncovered by the neural characterization project. The basic model uncovered by neuroscience has endorsed that we do not directly engage with the world, but with a highly crafted model of the world that our unconscious neurology constructs for us.

This neuroscience data is most similar to the model of sense datum theory than any of the other three listed in the SEP article.  Adverbial tends to deny real sense inputs, intentionality and disjunction theories tend to hold by versions of direct realism, and both are in pretty significant conflict with the above data, that perceptions are constructed by our-theory-laden unconsciousness, and qualia are then created to communicate the perceptions.

Classic sense-data theory also includes degrees of certainty about qualia and perception that have also been challenged by psychological testing on self-deception and our tendency to mislead ourselves -- so classic sense-data is also a suspect theory -- but one more amendable to match the neuroscience observations than any of the other three.

As the SEP article notes -- the idea that our unconscious neurology presents a perception to our consciousness -- is an intrinsically DUALIST model of mind/body that relies upon an aware Homunculus within our brains that the brains provide data to.  The objection to the intrinsic dualism of the Homunculus concept is the primary driver of the rejection of sense-datum theory.  However contemporary neuroscientists and mind researchers are postulating consciousness serving just this Homunculus role of a check upon our unconscious brains (see System 2 of Thinking Fast and Slow, and the executive manager of David Eagleman's Incognito).  This current research supports reconsidering sense-datum's Homunculus.

Not noted in the SEP article are the idealist models of perception which may have inspired your question.  Here is a recent idealist journal article: [The Philosophy of Perception : an explanation of Realism, Idealism and the Nature of Reality](https://hcommons.org/deposits/item/hc:26969/). Contemporary Idealism tends to argue for a "filter" view of consciousness and the mind -- that we have access to all the world, but our mind filters this data down and focusses on parts of the world that matter to us.  Why we can't then filter out distant objects that matter to us from those that don't when our eyes are injured, is a problem test case for such idealism.

Comment: +1 for another clear and helpful answer.